# Need help in using Eclipse Java EE version to develop a servlet project

Tags: eclipse, servlets

I have downloaded Eclipse Java EE version (3.5) and I would like to use it to develop a servlet project on tomcat.

So I

- install tomcat and add it as my server in my eclipse environment.
- create a Dynamic Web Project called 'TestServlet'
- create a new servlet called 'MainServlet'

and then I deploy my project to the tomcat server via eclipse and 'run the server in debug' mode.

But when I use the browser to hit `http://localhost:8080/TestServlet/MainServlet` I see no resource found (that page is generated by Tomcat, so I know my Tomcat is running).

Can you please tell me what am I missing?
Or how can I trouble shoot my problem?

I think it must be some path /name is not set correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify your servlet mapping is correct in web.xml

Answer (score 2):

1. Take a look at your web.xml file in your project. You should find an entry for your servlet and a mapping.

   ```
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>MainServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>your.package.MainServlet</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>MainServlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/main.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
   ```

Then the URL you use to access the servlet is:

```
    http://localhost:8080/main.do
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare your Servlet in the deployment descriptor (the `web.xml` file)? How did you map it? I suggest to check the [Servlet and JSP development with Eclipse WTP - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseWTP/article.html) or any other tutorial.